# Define a symbol with \stackrel, that works inline without changing the height of the line

Tags: stacking-symbols

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\mysymbol
{\ensuremath{\stackrel{(\mathsf{lin})}{\longrightarrow_{(1)}}}}


\begin{document}
  This is an example of what happens and what I want.
  I want this: \mysymbol\ to be inline but not to
  change the vertical line spacing. However, with
  \verb|\smash| I get $\smash{\mysymbol}$, which is
  not what I want. I want to change the symbol so it
  fits in a line, not to change the line so it
  superposes the symbol with another line. For example,
  \verb|\scalebox{1}[0.6]{\mysymbol}| almost works, but
  looks awful: \scalebox{1}[0.6]{\mysymbol}, and also
  changes the symbol. The most important would be not
  to change the shape of the \verb|\longrightarrow_{(1)}|.
\end{document}
```

Any proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tight, but it seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\linto}[1]{%
  \overset{\scriptscriptstyle\smash{(\mathsf{lin})}\vphantom{x}}{\longrightarrow_{(#1)}}%
}

\begin{document}

\lineskip=30pt % would kick in if lines have to be spread

This is an example of what happens and what I want.
I want this: $\linto{1}$ to be inline but not to
change the vertical line spacing.

\noindent
pypypypy\\
$\linto{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The high setting to `\lineskip` is to make evident the fact that lines have to be enlarged. Without the `\smash` we'd get

[image]

so we see that with `\smash` the `\lineskip` parameter doesn't kick in.

Comment: Great! Thanks! What is \vphantom used for?

Comment: @AlejandroDC Better to give the symbol a height that's not too far from the apparent one, in case spacing lines becomes necessary for other reasons: sometimes it's really unavoidable.